# Making any reference to Nodejs' process.argv causes errors in unexpected place (reading a file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, arguments

I am writing code that generates a very large JSON object, saves it to a file, then loads the file and inserts the data into a Mongo collection. I want to pass a string from the command line when calling the script that I use to set the file name, as well as the collection name. I call it like so: `node --max-old-space-size=8192 data_generator.js foo 1000000`.

The code fails with error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'foo.json'` on the third line of the function `gen_collection()` where I set the variable `data`. This error does not appear when a file `foo.json` already exists, even if it is empty. Before it fails, the code successfully creates a file `foo.json` but it contains only an empty array `[]`.

The code fails with this same exact error when I include any reference to process.argv. This includes when I try to set any variable to a value from the process.argv array. The code works when I set the variables `fname` as `const fname = "foo"` and `size` as `const size = 0`. However, even if the only reference I have to process.argv is in a console.log i.e. adding `console.log(process.argv[2]` to `main()`, it fails with the exact same error as above.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const fs = require('fs');
const bjson = require('big-json');

async function main() {
  const uri = "my db uri";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const fname = process.argv[2];
  const size = parseInt(process.argv[3]);
  // const fname = 'small'
  // const size = 1

  try {
    await client.connect({ useUnifiedTopology: true });
    await write_data_to_disk(fname, size);
    await gen_collection(client, fname);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};

// generate data as json aray and write to local file
async function write_data_to_disk(fname, size) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let doc = gen_document();
    arr.push(doc);
  }
  const strStream = bjson.createStringifyStream({
    body: arr
  })
  let logger = fs.createWriteStream(`${fname}.json`);
  strStream.on('data', (d) => {
    logger.write(d);
  })
};

async function gen_collection(client, fname) {
  let db = client.db('test');
  let collection = db.collection(fname);

  let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${fname}.json`, 'utf8')); // ERROR APPEARS ON THIS LINE
  bulkUpdateOps = [];
  data.forEach((doc) => {
    bulkUpdateOps.push({"insertOne": {"document": doc}});
    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
      collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
      bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
  })
  if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
    collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
  }
};

function gen_document() {
  // returns json object
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
await write_data_to_disk(...)
```

but that function doesn't return a promise that is connected to when it's done.  So, you're trying to read the resulting file BEFORE it has been created or before it has valid content in it and thus the `ENOENT` error as the file doesn't yet exist when you're trying to read from it in the following function.

Writestreams do not play nicely with promises unless you wrap them in your own promise that resolves when you are completely done writing to the stream and the file has been closed.

Also, you probably want to just `.pipe()` strStream to the logger stream.  Much easier and you can then just monitor when that pipe() operation is done to resolve the promise you wrap around that operation.

You can promisify `write_data_to_disk()` like this:

```
// generate data as json aray and write to local file
function write_data_to_disk(fname, size) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            let doc = gen_document();
            arr.push(doc);
        }
        const strStream = bjson.createStringifyStream({ body: arr });
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`${fname}.json`, {emitClose: true});

        // monitor for completion and errors
        dest.on('error', reject).on('close', resolve);
        strStream.on('error', reject);

        // pipe all the content from strStream to the dest writeStream
        strStream.pipe(dest);
    });
}
```

Since this returns a promise that is truly tied to when the write operation is done, you can then use `await write_data_to_disk(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That definitely seems like the issue. I don't entirely understand what you mean by using .pipe(), could you please explain how I could use it in this situation?

Comment: @jpc - See what I added to my answer.